How can I stop the Conan 2.0 CMakeDeps generator setting INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES?
I'm installing dependencies with Conan 2.0, specified in my conanfile.py. I don't want the cmake config files set INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES on any of the targets.
As a first step I tried to disable it for one package but it didn't work. Here's what I tried:
    def generate(self):
      deps = CMakeDeps(self)
      deps.set_property("zlib", "cmake_set_interface_link_directories", False)
      deps.generate()

The INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES is still set in ZLIB-Target-<config>.cmake. Should the code above work? I also tried "zlib/1.3.1" and "False". How to do it properly for one package and for all packages?

The property cmake_set_interface_link_directories seems outdated, just checked the code and the property will always exist, as it is necessary for transitive linking of shared libraries. There is a new "incubating" CMakeDeps in https://docs.conan.io/2/incubating.html that will try to avoid declaring it if possible (not clear yet). For further details or questions, better a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Thanks, then I'll just postprocess the generated cmake files to prevent setting it.
